# Adding options to a select using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

i have a button and when i click this button i want a select option added. I can add select but not options, why? I want it added according to the list.
Not adding 'foreach loop option'

[image]

```js
$(function () {
                var items = ["fa fa-address-book", "fa fa-address-book-o", "fa fa-address-card", "fa fa-address-card-o"];
                $('#add-menu').on('click', function (e) {
                    $('#menu').append('<li>\n' +
                        '<div class="row">\n' +
                        '<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Social Media İcon</label>\n' +
                        '<div class="col-sm-8">\n' +
                        ' <div class="form-group bmd-form-group" id="icon">\n' +
                        '<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="mySelect" name="icon[]" title="Social Media icon" data-live-search="true" ' +
                        'data-hide-disabled="true">\n' +
                        $.each(items, function (i, item) {
                            $('#mySelect').append($('<option>', {
                                value: item.value,
                                text: item.text
                            }));
                        }),
                        '</select>\n' +
                        '</div>\n' +
                        '</div>\n' +
                        '</div>\n' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</li>');
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menus">
    <ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="add-menu" class="btn">add-Menu</a>
```

Comment: `$.each(items, function (i, item)` -> `items` is not defined in your code snippit... Is that coming from code you have not included in your question?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean

Comment: Added Snippet..

Comment: can you add a sample of your desired outcome ?

Comment: If you check spinnet, option does not come

Comment: i mean what should it look like?

Comment: I want items to be installed as options.

Comment: There is a point I missed, but I didn't understand what happened.options are added as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite close; just replace `$.each()` with:

```
items.map(item => `<option>${item}</option>`).join('') +
```

as in this demo:

```js
$(function () {
                var items = ["fa fa-address-book", "fa fa-address-book-o", "fa fa-address-card", "fa fa-address-card-o"];
                $('#add-menu').on('click', function (e) {
                    $('#menu').append('<li>\n' +
                        '<div class="row">\n' +
                        '<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Social Media İcon</label>\n' +
                        '<div class="col-sm-8">\n' +
                        ' <div class="form-group bmd-form-group" id="icon">\n' +
                        '<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="mySelect" name="icon[]" title="Social Media icon" data-live-search="true" ' +
                        'data-hide-disabled="true">\n' +
                        items.map(item => `<option>${item}</option>`).join('') +
                        '</select>\n' +
                        '</div>\n' +
                        '</div>\n' +
                        '</div>\n' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</li>');
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menus">
    <ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="add-menu" class="btn">add-Menu</a>
```

**NOTE**

If you intend to add several `select` tags using the button `id="mySelect"` will be quite problematic in that you'll end up with more than one element having the same id attribute value. You don't want to end up there.

Comment: i know off topic but can i write items items php function?

Comment: I would not advise using PHP to create JS. It's better to put the data in a data attribute and JS can read it from there on the client side.

Comment: ```var items = [<?php foreach (icons() as $id => $icons): ?>"<?= $icons ?>",<?php endforeach; ?>];``` I ran it this way, it worked, do you mind?

Comment: Like I said, not a good idea. Ideally, **ALL** your JavaScript should be in a completely separate file.